# AWS RDS CPU Utilization high

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, cpu-usage

I am facing high CPU utilization issue on AWS RDS for MySQL. My development server feature: t2.medium (2CPU, 4GB RAM)
What could be the problem? Are there any ways to fix it? Kindly share your troubleshooting experiences.

Comment: Which DB are you running ?  What workload is running ?  Please add more details.

Comment: Hello @AdiDembak, Thanks for quick your response. It is AWS RDS for MySQL. Please be informed that suddenly its CPU utilization being high to 95%-98% almost. I use it for my website management.